# How to remove selected item from msflexgrid

Tags: vb6

I am using VB6 and in it I am using MSFlexGrid now i want to remove a complete row which is selected by user and once done it automatically Set focus to textbox, while searching over internet that is useful but the problem is when I click on the button it remove all the rows even the First row which is the header of FlexGrid and I don't want to remove the first row.

Here is that code

```
Private Sub cmdDell_Click()
Dim i As Integer

    With grdArticles 'the msflexgrid
        If .RowSel <> 0 Then 'check if there is a selected row
            For i = .RowSel To .Rows - 2 'loop from selected row to the las row
                .TextMatrix(i, 0) = .TextMatrix(i + 1, 0) 'set rows with 1 back
                .TextMatrix(i, 1) = .TextMatrix(i + 1, 1)
                .TextMatrix(i, 2) = .TextMatrix(i + 1, 2)
                .TextMatrix(i, 3) = .TextMatrix(i + 1, 3)
            Next i
                .Rows = .Rows - 1 'make the rows 1 less
        Else
            MsgBox "Selecet row to delete!!!", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only allow one row to be selected at a time you just need to use

Me.MSFlexGrid1.RemoveItem Me.MSFlexGrid1.RowSel

If you can have more than one row selected (user clicks and drags to select multiple) you would need to determine the range of rows selected and delete each row individually. The code on this page shows how to get the start and end selected row. You would need to loop in reverse when deleting the rows.

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_tell_flexgrid_rows_selected.html